# how can i restrict unregistered users from certain contents or pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-login

I am developing a website with wordpress that has a comment area in photo gallery and some tutorial videos page. how can i restrict unlogged users from giving comments and going to the video page. Till yet i have Google a lot but did not get any solution related my issue. I have already searched a lot of plugins but it was no use, 
For registration i am using pie register plugin my word-press theme is parabola.
 I tried to make some changes in comment.php file in theme folder:

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying Comments.
     *
     * The area of the page that contains both current comments
     * and the comment form. The actual display of comments is
     * handled by a callback to tc_comment_callback()
     *
     * @package Customizr
     * @since Customizr 1.0
     */

    /*
     * If the current post is protected by a password and
     * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
     * return early without loading the comments.
     */
     if ( have_comments() )
         echo apply_filters( 'tc_comment_separator', '<hr class="featurette-divider '. current_filter() .'">' );
?>

     <div id="comments" class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'tc_comments_wrapper_class' , 'comments-area' ) ?>" >
<?php 
     if( is_user_logged_in() )
     {
         comment_form( array( 'title_reply' => __( 'Leave a Comment' , 'customizr' ) ) );
         if ( have_comments() )
         do_action ( '__comment' );
      }
?>
    </div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
```

Comment: check it here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put a `!` before `is_user_logged_in()`.

For example:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Content shown for non-users
}

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Content shown for authorized users
}
```